# IBM RSA WTP Jax-rpc Create WS Client IWAB0639E WSWS3204E

Tags: java, wsdl, eclipse-wtp, rational-rsa

I need help on an error I get when trying to create a web service client in IBM RSA using the WTP wizard.
The error says :

```
IWAB0639E Error in generating Java files and deployment descriptors from WSDL file
  WSWS3204E: Error: {http:// [...] .com/ChannelSvcs/BranchMgmt/Schema/V1}OrganizationUnitCodeType already exists.
```

Couldn't find any hint to a solution on the net, only this one :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK40815

But this page also says :

`This updated WSDL2Java will be included in Rational Application Developer v6.0.1.2.`

But our environment is : `IBM RSA Version: 7.5.5.5 iFix001`

Build ID: `RSA4WSO7555iFix-I20121203_0630`

As a local fix this site suggests :
`Modify the existing wsdl structure so as not to include the same xsd file more than one time.`

But at this point I don't prefer a local fix, unless there's no permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I talked to the guy who published the web service and he told me to use the wsdl file in the documentation, not the wsdl file on the server (via URL).

so I did that and it worked.

Looks like the server sends all .xsd files and the .wsdl file mixing it into one response file.

Still, IMHO wsdl2java should still be able to process such files.